# How to get SSL connection of this function to work with GnuTLS build of RCurl

Tags: r, openssl, rcurl

I'm making an R package that interfaces with the api from opendata.socrata.com.

I've run into a problem, that I've tracked to the build of the RCurl package.

On windows, with the RCurl build with openSSL, I've got no problems, but on Linux, with GnuTLS, it doesn't work.

You can check the build using curlVersion()$ssl_version.

Here is the function:

```
search.Socrata.Views <- function(search = NULL, ## full
                                 topic = NULL, ## description
                                 name = NULL, ## title field search
                                 tags = NULL,
                                 category = NULL,
                                 count = FALSE,
                                 limit = 10, ## max 200
                                 page = 1,
                                 type = "json" ## can also be xml
){

  require('RCurl')
  require('XML')
  require('rjson')

  ## setting curl options
  capath = system.file("CurlSSL",package = "RCurl")
  cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "ca-bundle.crt", package = "RCurl")

  cookie = 'cookiefile.txt'
  curl  =  getCurlHandle ( cookiefile = cookie,
                           cookiejar = cookie,
                           useragent =  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en - US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6",
                           header = FALSE,
                           verbose = TRUE,
                           netrc = FALSE,
                           maxredirs = as.integer(20),
                           followlocation = TRUE,
                           ssl.verifypeer = TRUE,
                           cainfo = cainfo,
                           timeout = 100
                         )

  ## capath doesn't work:: NEED cainfo!
  ## test for existing cainfo:
  if (!file.exists(cainfo)){
    download.file('http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem', cainfo )
  }
  ## test for age of cainfo, if older than 2 weeks get new.
  if (file.exists(cainfo)){
    file.inf.cainfo <- file.info(cainfo)
    age.cainfo <- Sys.time() - file.inf.cainfo[["mtime"]]
    if(as.numeric(age.cainfo, units="days") > 14 ){
      download.file('http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem', cainfo )
    }
  }

  ### Make URL
  baseSocrataUrl <- 'https://opendata.socrata.com/api/views.'

  if(!is.null(category)){
    category <- match.arg( category, c('Business', 'Fun', 'Personal', 'Education', 'Government'))
  }
  type <- match.arg( type, c('json', 'xml'))

  ## Tag
  if(is.null(tags)){
    tags <- NULL
  } else {
    tags <- URLencode( paste('&tags=', tags, sep = ''))
  }
  ## Category
  if(is.null(category)){
    category <- NULL
  } else {
    category <- URLencode( paste('&category=', category, sep = ''))
  }
  ## Limit
  if(limit > 200){
    limit <- '&limit=200'
  } else {
    limit <- paste('&limit=', limit, sep = '')
  }
  ## search
  if(is.null(search)){
    search <- NULL
  } else {
    search <- URLencode( paste('&full=', search, sep = ''))
  }
  ## page
  page <- paste('&page=', page, sep = '')
  ## topic
  if(is.null(topic)){
    topic <- NULL
  } else {
    topic <- URLencode( paste('&description=', topic, sep = ''))
  }
  ## name
  if(is.null(name)){
    name <- NULL
  } else {
    name <- URLencode( paste('&name=', name, sep = ''))
  }
  ## count
  if(count){
    count <- '&count=TRUE'
  } else {
    count <- NULL
  }

  ### Retrieving html
  SocrataUrl <- paste( baseSocrataUrl, type, '?', page, tags, category, limit, search, name, topic, count, sep = '')
  SocrataHtml <- getURL(SocrataUrl, curl = curl)
  assign('search.Socrata.Call', SocrataUrl, envir=.GlobalEnv)
  if(type == 'json'){
    SocrataTable <- fromJSON(SocrataHtml)
    SocrataTable <- lapply( SocrataTable, function(x){data.frame( x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) } )
    SocrataTable.df <- data.frame( matrix( nrow = length( SocrataTable), ncol = max(unlist(lapply(SocrataTable, length) ) ) ) )
    names(SocrataTable.df) <- names( SocrataTable [lapply( SocrataTable, length ) == max( unlist( lapply( SocrataTable, length) ) ) ] [[1]] )
    for( i in 1: length( SocrataTable ) ){
      for( j in 1: length( names( SocrataTable[[i]] ) ) ){
        SocrataTable.df[i, names( SocrataTable[[i]] )[j]] <- SocrataTable[[i]][i, names( SocrataTable[[i]] ) [j] ]
      }
    }

    rm(curl)
    gc()

    return(SocrataTable.df)
  } else {

    rm(curl)
    gc()

    return(SocrataHtml)
  }
}
```

Run the function with:

```
socrata.views <- search.Socrata.Views(topic = 'airplane')
print(socrata.views)
```

Comment: You could also build RCurl with OpenSSL on Linux, just to rule out the impact of the sub-library.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested your code under Linux, but I can say that you're constructing URLs the hard way, which may be causing bugs.  Using `getForm`, you can simplify your code considerably.

```
params <- list(
  category = category,
  tags     = tags,
  limit    = min(limit, 200)
  #etc.
)
params <- Filter(Negate(is.null), params)
getForm(baseSocrataUrl, .params = params, curl = curl)
```

Comment: Unrelated to real problem, GnuTLS doesn't like pem-formatted certificate bundles, I'm looking for a solution too.